# Angular 2 - tsconfig outDir

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I'm currently developing an Angular2 application and I'm facing the following problem - I have some unit tests in my project and I don't want them to be sent to the /dist folder along side with my other code. My project structure is as follows:

```
dist/
 -app (compiled from src/app)
 -test (compiled from src/test)
src/
 -app
 -test
```

Now, using the "outDir" in my tsconfig.json I'm compiling all .js files to the /dist directory. What I want to do is simply compile all app/ ts files and send them to the /dist directory, but keep the compiled .js files from my /test directory there. It should look like this :

```
dist/
 -app (compiled from src/app)
src/
 -app
 -test ( all compiled js files remain here )
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
- src/
  - app/
  - test/
    - tsconfig.json
  - tsconfig.json
```

`tsconfig.json` for `src/`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist"
    [...]
  },
  "exclude": [],
  "include": ["./app"]
  [...]
}
```

`tsconfig.json` for `test/`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./"
    [...]
  },
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./"]
  [...]
}
```

#### Be careful to compile your code you will have to run `tsc` twice.

- From the `src` folder, to compile your application code.
- From the `test` folder, to compile your tests.